# How to install .net based windows service on fresh machine Win 7 Home

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, installutil

we have a windows service build using .net 4.5. Things were fine on development machine when i tried to install the same service on our UAT machine it is giving this below error, I have installed on this UAT machine. NET 4.5 only. After this below further below I have pasted the Fusion Log error please help.

```
C:\AuditServers\Services\AuditEngine\bin>ServiceInstall.bat Installing Service... Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version
4.0.30319.17929 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Exception occurred while initializing the installation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Dat a\AuditServer\Services\AuditEngine\bin\Audit.Services.AuditEngine.exe' or one of its d ependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.. Install Done. Press any key to continue . . .
```

## The Fusion Log

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (8/11/2013 @ 4:18:23 PM) ***

The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under executable  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = WIN-30DJ1MGM28A\VM-User LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = D:\Data\AuditServer\Services\AuditEngine\bin\Audit.Services.AuditEngine.exe LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL LOG: Cache Base = NULL LOG: AppName = InstallUtil.exe Calling assembly : (Unknown).
=== LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context. WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load(). LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe.Config LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config. LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/Data/AuditServer/Services/AuditEngine/bin/Audit.Services.AuditEngine.exe. LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Please any suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: have you tried to install it using a msi installer, instead of using a bat file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820899/creating-an-msi-installer-for-a-windows-service

Comment: No my dear I didn't tried to install it via installer, I will try and post my results back here soon.